# Ajax request and Firefox + Ghostery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox

I'm using this code for detecting ad blocker Ghostery:

```
    <script>
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200 ) {
      console.log('No blocker');
    }
    else if(request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 0){
      window.location.href = 'http://';
    }
  };
  request.open("GET","http://xx.net/pop.js");
  request.send();
  </script>
```

On Chrome works well but nothing on Firefox.

Some ideas?

Comment: are there any errors in Firebug console?

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(request.readyState + ":" + request.status);` to see what the state is in Firefox?  If its anything other than "4:200" or "4:0" your script will produce no output.

Comment: What is the doctype of the page where this script runs?

Comment: About docttype: the script is running in the viewer file, in index.html I see <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

Comment: No, I haven't tried with console.log(request.readyState + ":" + request.status); How I can try it?

Comment: @fedecoder `request.onreadystatechange = function() { console.log(request.readyState + ":" + request.status); }`

Comment: I see 2 errors in Console: ":" - viewer....312.jpg (riga 107) and "TypeError: $(...).jdMenu is not a function" -  jquery.jdMenu.js (linea 14, col 14)

Comment: The code works for me in Firefox v36.  Suggest using the Firefox debugger to step through the code.  If you need help with using the debugger then look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger

Comment: Indeed on Chrome+Ghostery it works but in Firefox+Ghostery not works.

Answer (score 0):

You should see what is going on when the readyState changes (that is, **if** it is changing). Pay attention to the readState and the status. Based on that, you can add more functions to be called for different scenarios.

```
request.onreadystatechange = function(){
console.log(this);
}
```

You have only defined events for when readyState is 4 and the status is either 200 or 0. There are so many other statuses that can be returned. Make sure that you are prepared for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved in this way:

```
 <script>
     $.ajax({url:"http://xx/pop.js",
     error: function() {
     window.location.href = 'http://';
     }});
</script>
```

If Ghostery block the url of my popup, the image with "AdBlock Detected" is showed.

This works perfectly on Firefox+Ghostery.